# Haskell function implementation depends on kind?

Tags: haskell

I'm reading a haskell tutorial, when reading type system kind part, i can't use replacement model to figure out function execute.

```
class Tofu t where
   tofu :: j a -> t a j

data Frank a b = Frank {frankField :: b a} deriving (Show)

instance Tofu Frank where
  tofu = Frank
```

I can understand j has type * -> *, t has type * -> (* -> *) -> *, and Frank kind is * -> (* -> *) -> *, match t, so can instance Tofu Frank, but tofu implementation let me confuse, if i do like this

```
tofu (Just 'a') :: Frank Char Maybe
```

(Just 'a') kind is *, Just is * -> *, match j a, i use replace model, Frank (Just 'a'), not make sense, Frank should get a * and a *->*, but if like this, should be Frank 'a' Just, make sense but syntax error, i want to know how this archive make replacement model work and syntax check.

Comment: Note that `Just 'a'` is nto a type, but a value. As such it has no kind `*`, but a type `Maybe Char`. Indeed, as you wrote below, you are confusing the type constructor `Frank :: * -> (*->*) -> *` with the value constructor `Frank :: b a -> Frank a b`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i get it,

```
 Frank a b
```

is type constructor, value constructor is

```
 Frank {frankField :: b a}
```

so

```
 tofu (Just 'a') = Frank {frankField = Just 'a'}
```

kind type match and replace model work.